# Neo4j query for getting first few nodes with highest degree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a total beginner with Neo4j and need help. Is there a query for getting the first few nodes with highest degree?

I have nodes called `P` and nodes called `A`. There are only links between `P` and `A` nodes. I want to have the first 10 nodes `P` which have the most links to nodes `A`.

My idea was the following query, but it took so much time!

```
MATCH (P1:P)-[r]->(A1:A)
RETURN P1.name AS P_name, COUNT(A1) AS A_no
ORDER BY no DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Best,

Mowi

Comment: Other than `ORDER BY no` as opposed to `ORDER BY A_no` no, the query looks fine.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! So it's probably a problem of my amount of data.

Answer (score 3):

How many nodes do you have in your db?

I'd probably not use cypher for that, the Java API actually has a `node.getDegree()` method which is much much faster.

Your query could be sped up a bit by

```
MATCH (P1:P)-->() 
RETURN id(P1),count(*) as degree 
ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10
```

you could also try:

```
MATCH (P1:P)
RETURN id(P1),size((P1)-->()) as degree 
ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10
```

for limiting the nodes:

```
MATCH (P1:P)
WHERE P1.foo = "bar"
WITH P1 limit 10000
MATCH (P1)-->() 
RETURN id(P1),count(*) as degree 
ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi!

I tested your improved query and it still takes too long time. I've 120 million nodes in my db and approx. 190 million relationships. So this is probably the problem.

First, I'm going to find out how to use Java combined with Neo4j.

Second, is there an option to apply the query only to an arbitrary part of my nodes?

Thank you very much!